# z390 break points, files, parmfield

Tags: debugging, assembly, breakpoints

(1) In z390 test, my break points are not being set.

(2) I'd like to know how to specify a parmfield.

(3) I'd like to know how to associate a file to be used.

(4) At 77, I remember some 360 assembler. I'm a dunce on a PC.

(5) I think I need a .bat file to do the test-run, but am not sure how to do that.

(6) This is an exercise to see if I have any remaining functioning brain cells.

(7) for background, my BAL program to find 2339 solutions to the Pentominoes puzzle (Hexed) ran in 71 seconds in 1990.  Originally 21 minutes on a 360/95.

(8) I do wonder how I'll know if there's an answer?  linlyons aat yahoo works.

```
test cmd: b=0fff00  (note, memory displays are strange)

00000320 *00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000*

test cmd: A 002C

 00000002 *00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000*

test cmd: A 003C

 00000003 *00000000 00000000 00000000 00000020*

test cmd: g   (ran right through my break points)

NO PARM OR PARM LONGER THAN 15 CHARS

EZ390I Trace Table Entry      800FFF30 58210000     L    
EZ390I Trace Table Entry      800FFF34 48320000     LH   
EZ390I Trace Table Entry      800FFF38 4930D0B0     CH   
EZ390I Trace Table Entry      800FFF3C 4720D048     BH   
EZ390I Trace Table Entry      800FFF40 4B30D0B2     SH   
EZ390I Trace Table Entry      800FFF44 4720D080     BH   
EZ390I Trace Table Entry      800FFF48 A7150016     BRAS 
EZ390I Trace Table Entry      800FFF74 0A23         SVC  
EZ390I Trace Table Entry      800FFF76 4400D076     EX   
EZ390E error  11 ABEND PSW=07051600 800FFF76 4400D076     EX    ABEND S0C3
```

Comment: Lin, welcome.  Lots of items in your list.  I'm not familiar with Z390 test.  Can you provide a link to this so I can better understand your environment?

Comment: www.z390.com
It's a cobol / assembler 390 emulator that allows testing on your PC at home.
Hercules is another emulator, that appears to be a more accurate representation of an IBM 390 environment, but z390 works well enough for me -- well, would work well enough for me, if I could get it to work.

Comment: it's  z390.org  (didn't realize my mistake for more'n 5 minutes)

Comment: Lin, you can notify other people when you reply to their comments by using @Hogstrom in your comment.  Otherwise only the person whose question/answer you comment under gets notified.